# Normalizing dataset with ruby

Tags: ruby, normalizing

I have a data set that ranges from 1 to 30,000

I want to normalize it, so that it becomes 0.1 to 10

What is the best method/function to do that?

Would greatly appreciate it if you could give some sample code!

Comment: Are you sure this is called data normalization?  You may consider calling this data transformation, I believe normalization refers to the topology of data.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's a code snippet, assuming you want a *linear* normalization. It's a very simplistic version (just straight code, no methods), so you can see "how it works" and can apply it to anything.

```
xmin = 1.0
xmax = 30000.0
ymin = 0.1
ymax = 10.0

xrange = xmax-xmin
yrange = ymax-ymin

y = ymin + (x-xmin) * (yrange / xrange)
```

---

And here it is done as a function:

```
def normalise(x, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
  xrange = xmax - xmin
  yrange = ymax - ymin
  ymin + (x - xmin) * (yrange.to_f / xrange) 
end

puts normalise(2000, 1, 30000, 0.1, 10)
```

(Note: the `to_f` ensures we don't fall into the black hole of integer division)

Comment: Thanks brent! that is a nice and elegant way of doing this =)

Answer (score 9):

This is a well known way to scale a collection numbers. It has more precise name but I can't remember and fail to google it.

```
def scale(numbers, min, max)
    current_min = numbers.min
    current_max = numbers.max
  numbers.map {|n| min + (n - current_min) * (max - min) / (current_max - current_min)}
end

dataset = [1,30000,15000,200,3000]
result = scale(dataset, 0.1, 10.0)
=> [0.1, 10.0, 5.04983499449982, 0.165672189072969, 1.08970299009967]
scale(result, 1, 30000)
=> [1.0, 30000.000000000004, 15000.0, 199.99999999999997, 3000.0000000000005]
```

As you can see, you have to be aware of rounding issues. You should probably also make sure that you don't get integers as min & max because integer division will damage the result.

Answer (score 9):

Here's the Ruby Way for the common case of setting an array's min to 0.0 and max to 1.0.

```
class Array
  def normalize!
    xMin,xMax = self.minmax
    dx = (xMax-xMin).to_f
    self.map! {|x| (x-xMin) / dx }
  end
end

a = [3.0, 6.0, 3.1416]
a.normalize!
=> [0.0, 1.0, 0.047199999999999985]
```

For a min and max other than 0 and 1, add arguments to `normalize!` in the manner of Elfstrom's answer.

Answer (score -2):

`x = x / 3030.3031 + 0.1`

Comment: This answer would benefit greatly from an explanation of how you came to these numbers and stuff.  It's not wrong, it's just not enough information in case someone doesn't immediately understand why this works.